# Trying to 'Go Live' with our DocuSign integration but no audit logs and "Review Failed"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

We have created a DocuSign integration within our Microsoft Word add-in using [the C# wrapper library from GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) (compiled version: v1.6.1.0) and we are now trying to 'Go Live' by following the instructions [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live).

Unfortunately we have performed 20+ test transactions as required but we cannot see them in the audit logs and when we proceed with the process of reviewing the transactions - the system eventually returns "Review Failed".

We checked the account details (urls + keys) and everything matches.

In our audit logs we cannot see any of the recent activity...

Any idea what we are doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see the transaction in the Demo account where resides the Integrator Key you're trying to certify ?

Comment: @Frederic not sure what you mean? On the website there is no audit logs for today or recent times...

Comment: The 20+ transactions you have created, can you see them actually processed in your DocuSign account/sandbox ?

Comment: @Frederic - No unfortunately not... I think that is part of the problem. My audit logs end on 12th July 2016. App integration has not changed since then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to Enable API Request Logging :
https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/API-Request-Logging

Comment: not sure why someone voted this down without commenting on it... any ideas? i'll give this a go and let you know how it goes...

Comment: I can see all my requests here... Still nothing in the Audit Logs in the new view... What next?

Comment: Even though we still didn't see any audit logs this actually made it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main things you should check when a review fails:

1. Confirm you have run 20+ consecutive, error-free API transactions that comply with [API Rules and Limits](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#api-rules).
2. Confirm you have run your API transactions under the same integrator key you have selected to review.
3. Ensure you are inputting the correct test date for your API transactions during the first step.
4. Review the API logs of your sandbox account to ensure your integration is making the expected API requests.
5. Confirm other users of your sandbox account are not making additional API requests during your transactions testing.

This plus the go live steps can be found here:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#enable-key

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The app integration has not changed and yet for some reason the audit logs stop on the 12th July 2016... No activity shown since then. Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly we can see the various recent actions we performed on the User side ie. `appdemo.docusign.com/home > Overview` but not in the Admin side ie. `admindemo.docusign.com/audit-log`

Comment: is there any other way to get assistance with this? Is there someone we can talk to @ DocuSign? We really need to push this forward...